# How to parse json page using gson?

Tags: android, json, gson

I have a large json page which contains url:http://akhilmadanan.tk/Akhil/database.php.
While i am parsing this page using normal json parsing method it shows "OutOfMemoryError". For this i heard about GSON. Please any body help me get how to read the datas from below page using GSON.
any tutorial?

Comment: Like JoxTraex mentioned first step is to break you db into chunks

Comment: i think GSON can use for this??

Comment: Try this http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html look at com.google.gson.stream -> Class JsonReader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely go to links provided by others which are helpful

For brief you can add GSON library in your lib folder.
and use like this.

```
Gson gson=new Gson();
```

To get object from json

```
Model model=gson.fromJson(json,Model.class);
```

To convert to json

```
String json=gson.toJson(model);
```

I run your code and there are 3010 items of object

```
[
{
"cust_no":"70105615002",
"cust_name":"akhil",
"address":"kajffjkhfhhkjsd",
"area":"58695",
"ranges":"4586",
"plot":"69896",
"multifactor":"85758",
"electricity_meterno":"7895",
"water_meterno":"69358",
"gas_metrno":"78956",
"traffic_code":"4587855",
"last_meter":"58695",
"previous_reading":"25638",
"date":"589687",
"current_usage":"789654",
"current_balance":"45876",
"last_recipt":"236584"
},....
```

Now make a model equivalent to above name like

```
@SerializedName("cust_no")
private Long custNo;

@SerializedName("cust_name")
private Long custName;

..........
```

remember to add one list of same class type like

```
 @SerializedName("custname")
private List<Customer> customerList;
```

and generate getters and setters of that Customer class;

after this

parse your data like this

CustomerModel customerModel=gson.fromJson(json,Customer.class);

you get all your data in customerModel;

To access data just use list of that class.

```
List<Customer> customerList=customerModel.getCustomerList();

Log.v("APP_NAME",""+customerList.size());
```

Comment: can u able to help me to parse the data form http://akhilmadanan.tk/Akhil/database.php.

Comment: i dont nkow how getCustomeList() is working in...List<Customer> customerList=customerModel.getCustomerList();

Comment: have you generated getters setters, if yes then getCustomerList(); is method in your Customer model class, please check your Customer model class for getter method of that list

Comment: i dont know how to create getters and setters

Comment: right click on your model class, here you find source, under source you will find generate getters and setters

Answer (score 2):

Here'a good tutorial:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

You can also check out their official user guide:

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning all the data, why don't you break it into chunks? That would require less memory at processing time.

Thats assuming you have access to the database level/response.